# Cost of conversion between integral types

Tags: c++, optimization, type-conversion, overloading

I am creating a supplemental library of math functions for use in my programs, and wish to implement a [gcd function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor). I may end up using this function frequently, so optimization is *extremely important*.

I am wondering if, with regard to optimization, there is any point in implementing several gcd overloads for different integral types. As illustration:

```
int gcd(const int lhs, const int rhs);
long gcd(const long lhs, const long rhs);
long long gcd(const long long lhs, const long long rhs);
```

Is there any inherent cost when converting between integral types, or can I just implement the `long long` version and call it "good enough"?

Comment: Look at your compiler manual of choice for questions like these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first of all, you can just template it:

```
template <typename T>
T gcd(const T lhs, const T rhs);
```

And call `gcd<int>(a, b)` or whichever type you need, if your primary concern is simply code duplication.

That said, while I doubt that integral type conversion would ever show up in profiling, this is the sort of thing that you should first write in the most convenient way and worry about optimizing it if and when you actually have to optimize it.

Comment: I'd considered this, too, but then I have no control over the template parameter

Comment: Ooh... unless a `static_assert` is used. Perhaps this will do.

Comment: @Conduit why would it matter, your compiler will automatically increase type size as needed and they're both signed so it's not like your logic would change.

Comment: @Conduit You definitely have control over the template parameter. You can explicitly specify it. For instance, `int a = 20, b = 5; long long c= gcd<long long>(a, b);`

Comment: No - I mean there's potential weirdness at work if I don't limit the allowed parameter types. `gcd<float>`, for example, would make no sense despite having all the necessary ops. That could end in an infinite loop in certain situations.

Comment: @Conduit You could just not call it with `float`. And if you're worried about gcd performance, probably just not use `float` period. But if you're really concerned, `static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "must be integral type.");`

Comment: Yep - that's the plan. Testing in a moment.